# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push' node js

Tags: node.js

```
when I am trying to add the object to array it while push it in the array I am unable to get push.

   console.log('starting password manager');

        var storage = require('node-persist');
        storage.initSync();

        // account.name Facebook
        // account.username User12!
        // account.password Password123!
        accounts = [];
        function createAccount (account) {
            var accounts = storage.getItemSync('accounts');

            if (typeof accounts === 'undefined') {
                accounts = [];
            }

            accounts.push(account);
            storage.setItemSync('accounts', accounts);

            return account;
        }
         createAccount({
        name: 'Facebook',
        username: 'someemail@gmail.com',
        password: 'Password123!'
    });
```

I am using npm node-persist to store the var. which will save my used to save the var and push the aobject on the existing saved array.I am using npm node-persist to store the var. which will save my used to save the var and push the aobject on the existing saved array.

Comment: Check the value of `accounts` before pushing.

Comment: I deleted the npm log file and all the variables files from the persist folder and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs it looks like `storage.getItemSync` returns a value (which may or may not be an array). Thus, I would recommend adding a check: `if(!Array.isArray(accounts)){ accounts = []; }` and then proceeding.

Comment: I deleted the npm log file and all the variables files from the persist folder and now its working fine.